# Terminate and restart animation if executed again while still in progress

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Button that animates a Label's text (Hello World!) in a typewriter style every time I press it. If I press the Button while the animation's still in progress, the text prints itself again at the current point of the animation, resulting in stuff like this:

> HellHello World!o World!

I'm using an extension, so I can't add variables and I'm not sure how to execute the animation without the `UILabel` extension. What would be the easiest way to fix this?

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    self.label.animate(newText: label.text ?? "Hello World!", characterDelay: 0.05)
}

extension UILabel {
    func animate(newText: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = ""
            for (index, character) in newText.enumerated() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + characterDelay * Double(index)) {
                    self.text?.append(character)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/cl7/CLTypingLabel

Comment: I'd prefer not to work with CocoaPods

Comment: then you can just drag and drop source file and use it

Comment: This “dispatch many `asyncAfter` calls” pattern is one to be avoided because (a) it can’t (easily) be stopped; and (b) you’ll be subject to timer coalescing (i.e. latter calls will not fire at the desired time interval, but rather start coalescing them together to save power). Use `Timer`. And you can `invalidate` timers to stop them.

Comment: “I'm using an extension, so I can't add variables”. You’ll need variables to keep track of the state of this animation. I might suggest a `UILabel` subclass instead. If you _absolutely_ need this to be an extension, you can use “associated objects” to store these state variables. But that’s kludgy, IMHO.